# Where is default sql file for PuppetDb?

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

I'd like to make some slight modifications to PuppetDB (adding a few columns and a table).

I've been reading through the [source code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb) and I can't seem to find the default structure that is setup on PuppetDb's initial install.

I need to modify the original source rather than simply ssh'ing in after the fact so I can save the initial setup into a docker file.

Does anyone know where in the source code the sql structure is defined?

Comment: A search for the term **schema** may give you results.  That is the term that is used to describe a databases structure.  But apparently the devs, really don't think you should be doing that.  https://ask.puppet.com/question/14859/looking-for-puppetdb-schema-documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with @Zoredache's suggestion I started searching through the repository for instances of schema. Then I searched some of the specific table names and I was able to find a clojure file where all the table creation tables seem to originate from.

[Migrate.clj](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb/blob/a07d725f333ffc5c77ca9fc217be4843150406cd/src/puppetlabs/puppetdb/scf/migrate.clj#L69)